# Elasticsearch - Integration of Elasticsearch with Spring + Mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Currently I am working on application related to Spring boot + Mongodb. Although application is working fine, but there are some collections where some fields are statis/required and others are totally dynamic.
Example:

```
@Document(collection = "yyyEntry")
public class YYYEntry{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String yyyId;
    private String yyyNumber;
    private List<KeyValueVo> customFields;
    //...
}

    public class KeyValueVo {

    private String field;
    private Object value;
}
```

Where `field` field in `KeyValueVo` can hold any value. And there can be a list of such pairs. Now although I can search document by these `fields` in mongodb, but its performance is too low(There can be a very large number of such records!), and this completely looks like a **Complete Textual Search**.

So for this purpose, we decided to integrate [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) with Mongodb for searching purpose. I have integrated Elasticsearch with Spring boot and working fine, but came to know that Elasticsearch is using/storing same data in its own format in its own storage and not using data of Mongodb.(Data Duplication!)

So my questions are:

1. Can we configure Elasticsearch to  use data of mongodb?(Remove
   Data duplication)
2. If question-1 is impossible, then how  can I store data in both Mongodb/ElasticSearch-engine using spring boot at the same time?
3. Is it good to use Elasticsearch with Mongodb?
4. Is it good to use **Elasticsearch MongoDB River** for that purpose?

No need for code implementations, just need simple guidelines, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like a case of early optimisation for me. Is data duplication really a problem for your app?

Comment: @msparer Not just problem of Duplication, there are so many others like same data would have to be written to both Mongodb + Elasticsearch engine in each creation/update request(too time wasting!). Similarly other downside is what if some data is successfully written to one database but failed to be written to other one(Data inconsistency) and can be so many others

Comment: Did you find a solution ? @Afridi